# How to make a program wait for mouse click before proceeding

Tags: events, python-3.x, mouseevent

I'm working on a program that is supposed to iterate between two points to find the root of a function, given a certain tolerance. My plan was to plot the function and then have the user specify two points by clicking in the plot. My problem is that I havn't found any way to "paus" the program until two points have been specified, it just keeps going. For example, the code below gives IndexError: list index out of range when trying to print coords[0][0]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    

def on_press(event):
    print('you pressed', event.button, event.xdata, event.ydata)

    global ix, iy 
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata

    coords = coords.append([ix, iy])

    if len(coords) >1:
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)

def get_clicks(fig):
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_press)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.show()

coords = []

get_clicks(fig)

print(coords[0])
```

What I  want to do, is have the code wait at "get_clicks(fig)" until two clicks has been made, and then continue with the rest of the code.

Update.

The code now looks like this:

```
def bisec(a,b,tol):

    print("Hi there!")
    return a,b,mid

def on_press(event):
    print('you pressed', event.button, event.xdata, event.ydata) 

    global ix, iy 
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata

    if len(coords)<=1:
        global coords
        coords.append([ix, iy])

    if len(coords) >1:
        #fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
        print(coords)
        bisec(coords[0][0], coords[1][0], 10)

def get_clicks(fig):
    global cid    
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_press)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

coords = []

get_clicks(fig)

plt.show()
```

The purpose of all this i to call bisec when 2 coordinates has been provided, which seems to be the result at the moment, splendid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plt.show
should go just before the last line.

coords should be declared global.
And
    coords = coords.append([ix, iy])
should be replaced by
    coords.append([ix, iy])

Regarding your last question, yes it is possible.
The general idea is to put the code "inside" the:

```
if len(coords) >1:
```

For example:

```
if len(coords) >1:
    do_what_I_mean(coords)
```

If you really want to write:
    fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
you should be careful to make sure that:

1) cid is a global variable
(easiest way: don't make a function get clicks, just write its content in the script)

2) and is declared as such in the on_press function

Comment: Thanks! Now coords store coordinates correctly, however, I still need to have the code wait for 2 mouse clicks. I know this is possible in Java for example, is there a similar possibility in python?

Comment: Saw it just now, thank you!
Getting some progress, I'll update the original question to the current code.